# Replace value in dataframe non-conditionally with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the `dplyr` function (if any) for `df[df == 2] <- 3`?

(i.e. replace all values of 2 in the dataframe `df` by 3)

With `dplyr` I could do that as:

```
df %>% mutate_all(funs(ifelse(.==2, 3, .)))
```

Is there a function such as `recode_all(df, old_value=2, new_value=3)`?

Comment: It works as ``df %>% mutate_all(recode(., `2` = 3))``.

Comment: it's not a `dplyr` function but you can use `replace`, `df %>% mutate_all(funs(replace(., .==2, 3,)))`

Comment: @RonakShah Indeed, a similar solution I proposed in the question. But I did not manage to find a straight-forward `dplyr` function for this. I was wondering whether I miss something...

Comment: `recode` *is* a `dplyr` function, and I think `mutate_all` with `recode` or `replace` is as straightforward and `dplyr`ish as you can get. What would make it more straightforward in your opinion?

Comment: @camille See my question please. I wanted to know whether I miss a function designed specially for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   replace(.< 22, "smaller_22")
```

Answer (score 1):

thats a pretty good one in my opinion:

```
df1 <- mtcars[1:4,1:4]
df1 %>% `[<-`(., . < 22, value = "smaller_22")
```

---

so in your special case:

```
df %>% `[<-`(., . == 2, value = 3)
```

Comment: Nice option with `[<-` . I haven't used it so far but it is something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
df %>% mutate_all(funs(case_when(.==2 ~ 3, TRUE ~ as.numeric(.))))
```

(not sure why it wants me to change it to numeric, but just putting in `.` at the end gave an error...)